# MySQL/PHP - Checkbox array to delete multiple rows from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, checkbox

i'm having some trouble passing Form checkbox array as mysql_query in order to delete multiple rows from table.

The structure is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<form action="usunogrod.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php
     $ogrodysql = "SELECT id_ogrodu, nazwa FROM ogrody";
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $ogrodysql);

     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              echo "• " . $row["id_ogrodu"]. " " . $row["nazwa"]. "<input type='checkbox' name='removegarden[]' value=" .$row["id_ogrodu"]." <br><br>";
         }
     } 
     else {
         echo "0 results";
     }
     ?>

    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Usuń zaznaczony ogród."/>
</form>
```

**PHP for processing form in usunogrod.php**

```
<?php

$db_host = 'xxxxx';
$db_user = 'xxxxx';
$db_pwd = 'xxxxx';
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd);  
$database = 'xxxxx';

if (!mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Brak połączenia z bazą danych.");

if (!mysqli_select_db($con, $database))
    die("Nie można wybrać bazy danych.");

function sql_safe($s)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $s = stripslashes($s);
    global $con;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $s);
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {   

    $ogrod_id = trim(sql_safe($_POST['removegarden[]']));

    if (isset($_POST['removegarden[]'])) {

                mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM ogrody WHERE id_ogrodu='$ogrod_id'");

                $msg = 'Ogród został usunięty.';
    }
    elseif (isset($_GET['removegarden[]']))
        $msg = 'Nie udało się usunąć ogrodu.';
};
?>
```

**MySQL table**

```
ogrody

#      id_ogrodu      nazwa
       1              garden1
```

How may i process an **array** from checkboxes form so that i will be able to pass a query to delete all checked elements?

**EDIT:**

I have been able to make it work to a moment where it only deleted one of the checked positions, or the other time just got an error saying i can't pass and array to mysqli_query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should help you:

Change this line:

```
echo "• " . $row["id_ogrodu"]. " " . $row["nazwa"]. "<input type='checkbox' name='removegarden[]' value=" .$row["id_ogrodu"]." <br><br>";
```

For this one:

```
echo '• ' . $row["id_ogrodu"]. ' ' . $row["nazwa"]. '<input type="checkbox" name="removegarden['.$row["id_ogrodu"].']" value="'.$row["id_ogrodu"].'" /> <br/><br/>';
```

Then this one:

```
if (isset($_POST['removegarden[]'])) {
```

To

```
if (isset($_POST['removegarden'])) {
```

And finally your query:

```
$gardens = implode(',',$_POST['removegarden']);
mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM ogrody WHERE id_ogrodu IN($gardens)");
```

Comment: Works perfect, same method as B. Desai proposed - you were just one minute later! :) Thanks for explaining in detail, apart from that i cannot change the value in html/php markup, since it needs to be used for further processing, your answer was of great value, thanks!!!

Comment: I forgot to change that sorry. It should be the id of course that you are concatenating before your query.. edited the second snippet paste.

Comment: i changed top answer to yours since it provides more in-detail way of thinking on this problem, therefore might be a little bit more useful for any1 to come over this. have a nice day, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You can get your data in `$_POST['removegarden']`. no need `[]` at last.

Then convert this array to ',' seperated string which can be then used in query

```
if (isset($_POST['removegarden'])) {
$ids_to_delete = implode(",",$_POST['removegarden']);
                mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM ogrody WHERE id_ogrodu IN ($ids_to_delete)");

                $msg = 'Ogród został usunięty.';
    }
```

Comment: works perfect, even though i had to remove sql_safe function it works like a charm, thanks!